# Regex for 0-2 including decimals up to two decimals it should include 0,1,2 the range from 0.00 to 2.00 ^([.]?[0-1][.]?[0-9]{0,2}|2)$

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried so many regex for range from 0.00 to 2.00 with following

```
^([.]?[0-1][.]?[0-9]{0,2}|2)$
```

Its accepting 111 or 101 or 011 which are invalid.

Comment: Hit up https://regex101.com, put in your regexp, and read the explanation for it. If you need "the number zero, one, or two, then maybe a period, and if there was a period, up to two more numbers" then pretty much "write that": `[012]`, and then an optional group `(...)?` that captures that period and subsequent numbers.

Comment: Are you trying to match strings or numbers? If strings are like oranges, then numbers are apples -- oranges and apples are different even though they are both fruits. It sounds like you are trying to make orange pie instead of apple pie. 
Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Do you want to match if there isn’t a zero before the decimal point (e.g., “.01”)?

Comment: Give some examples of what input is. Is the input exactly one digit, a dot, and 2 digits? Is the input a series of digits and dots delimited by spaces? ex. on a single line: 011 1.0 1.95 2.11.

Answer (score 1):

I would complete Nicholas Carey's regex so that it also accepts following valid JS numbers (afaik), meeting the awaited range condition:
1.
.27
001.31
+1.99

```
/^\+?0*((2(\.0?0?)?)|((0?|1)(\.[0-9]?[0-9]?)?))$/
```

However, if your need is in JS (and not in a html pattern or similar), I would advise NOT using a regex.
Something like this would be much easier to understand and maintain:

```
function checkRange(value, min, max){
  return !isNaN(value) && value>=min && value<=max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^                         # - Anchor the match to start-of-text, followed by
(                         # - A group, consisting of alternatives. Either
  (                       #     - a group, itself consisting of
    2                     #         - the integer 2, followed by
    (\.00?)?              #         - an optional decimal fraction of zero (`.0` or `.00`)
  )                       #
|                         #     OR
  (                       #     - a group, itself consisting of
    [0-1]                 #         - the integers `0` or `1`, followed by
    (\.[0-9][0-9]?)?      #         - an optional decimal fraction of 1 or 2 digits
  )                       #
)                         # The whole of which is followed by
$                         # - end-of-text
```

Turned into a function,

```
const isBetweenZeroAndTwo = /^((2(\.00?)?)|([0-1](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?))$/.test ;
```

Which can be invoked as `isBetweenZeroAndTwo( '1.23' )`.